# NVME SSD speed difference on clean Windows 10 vs Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance, windows-server-2016, nvme

I have tested console command `winsat diskformal` to see read speeds of NVME SSD disk. I have done it twice on really clean (with the Chipset and ME driver) Windows 10 Pro and Windows Server 2016 StdDesktop. I don't understand, why results are different?

Windows 10 — 2500+ Sequential, 2200+ Random

Windows Server 2016 — 2500 Sequential (avg few percent smaller than 10), **700+ (!)** Random

I have checked NVME driver, it same in both OS. Also I tried to use other NVME driver, results are same.

Obviously, there is something missing in Server OS, but what?

Upd: So, this is what we have:

Win10: 2500, 2200 after install, same after 2,5,10 minutes, 2500, 1500 with CPU stress test

Win2016: 2500, 2200 after install, 2500, 700 after 2, 5, 10 minutes. Same results after reboot.

What in Win2016 can affect disk speed after 2-3 minutes after reboot? My first thought was about Services. So, I checked services when speed was good, and then when speed become slow. After that, I disable all services except one, but this does not help.

Comment: Just checked ``diskformal`` on Windows Server 2012 R2: results are same to 10 (2500+ & 2300+)... Probably my WS2016 distributive is bad? Will check.

Comment: This is strange... I've just installed clean MSDN WS2016 and got good results. I've ever posted answer to this question, but when I checked againg — I got 2500+ & 700+. How? HOW??? This is not about temperature throttle (47 degrees in SMART). Probably it comes from low, but constant WS2016 disk activity? Looks like I can get good results within 1-2 minutes after reboot.

Comment: So, waiting 2 minutes after boot has completed gets you better results, or running the test less than 2 minutes after a reboot gets better results? It's unclear from your comment.